# recursive program including scanfs in C

Tags: c, recursion, scanf

I am trying to write a recursive function like that

```
int nestedExpression(){
    
    char expCh;
    scanf(" %c", &expCh);
  

    if(expCh == '\n'){
        return 0;
    }
 
    nestedExpression();


    \\deal with the return
    return 0;
```

now my input is (1 + 1) and while it gets to the character ) it's treating it as it was '\n'.

Comment: Where in this code do you handle the brackets?

Comment: For what it's worth, writing a parser using `scanf` can be quite counter-productive. Writing your own state-machine based parser using the raw string itself and some simple `char*` pointers isn't that hard and gives you way more flexibility in processing, especially when dealing with an arbitrary number of spaces or elements which may or may not be present.

Comment: `expCh` can never be `'\n'` because `'\n'` is a whitespace character, and the space character in `" %c"` skips whitespace characters.

Comment: What makes you think that ')' is treated as '\n'. What is the expected behavior of your code and how it actually behaves?

Answer (score 0):

Think about this bit

```
scanf(" %c", &expCh);


if(expCh == '\n'){
    return 0;
}
```

You do nothing with expCh when it is not '\n', later you always

```
return 0;
```

Which I suppose is why you think every character is treated as '\n'.

Also you do nothing with the result of your recursive call

```
nestedExpression();
```

You need to assign this to a variable.